# Why is my global variable not being initialized?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm trying to create a singleton object in my ASP.NET web app. The definition is like this:

```
Public Module Providers
    Public AppConnectionStringProvider As IConnectionStringProvider
End Module
```

And I'm setting this in `Global.asax` like this:

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ...
    'create a default connection string provider
    AppConnectionStringProvider = New MyConnectionStringProvider
    ....
End Sub
```

This works fine, but sometimes I see errors in my log file that are caused, ultimately, by using `AppConnectionStringProvider` when it is `Nothing/null`. I thought that by initializing it in `Application_Start` I would guarantee that this variable is always non-null, but there seem to be some circumstances where this is not so. What could cause this? I'm thinking of threading issues, but I can't see what they would be.

**Edit**: Below is the stack trace. Roughly, it's a simple request for the site home page:

```
Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep
System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep
System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute
ASP.default_aspx.ProcessRequest
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain
System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive
MyApp.Default.Page_Load.21[Default.aspx.vb]
...
MyApp.SomeModule..ctor.6[Utilities.vb]
MyApp.get_ConnectionString.70[Connections.vb]
```

And in that last method, at that line of code, it's trying to use the object that was initialized in `Application_Start`, but it seems to be null, when it should have a value.

Comment: Just change your declaration?  `Public AppConnectionStringProvider As IConnectionStringProvider = New MyConnectionStringProvider`

Comment: It's worth pointing out that you have not created singleton there.  A singleton would be a class that guarantees that only one instance exists at a time.  Modules can be instantiated so they can't have a single instance.

Comment: Have you debugged?  Do these exceptions get thrown before that line in Application_Start is executed or after?  Where are the exceptions thrown?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Wait...VB.Net `module` can be instantiated?

Comment: Oops! No, modules can't be instantiated. That's what I meant to post earlier but missed a rather important "'t": Modules CAN'T be instantiated so they can't have a single instance. If there's no instances at all then there can't be a single instance.

Comment: @SLaks: I added the call stack to the question.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: VB modules are global, so a public property in a module should only have a single value app wide. I just can't figure out why it's having NO value here.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank, I'm not trying to say that the module doesn't serve your purpose and I'm not trying to provide a solution to your problem, hence the comment rather than an answer. I just wanted to point out that what you have is NOT a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

If your singleton object should dispose at sessions end then add your object to a session variable. Session[MyConnectionStringProvider] = New MyConnectionStringProvider(). alternatively if you'd like your singleton object to be alive for the application and share it with all users then add it to an application variable. Application[MyConnectionStringProvider] = New MyConnectionStringProvider.  This way your object will not be null and available for all requests. I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't want to put it into the application, because my ultimate goal is to be able to inject different providers so I can use my web code in non-web contexts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be a very subtle sequencing issue. I had a class that referenced the `AppConnectionStringProvider` object, but the code that set the provider object had a constructor that implicitly created an object that created another object that created *another* object that depended on the provider. So even though it looked like the object could not be null, the code that set it depended on it not being null. I had to refactor a bit to disentangle these dependencies, but now it's working fine. Thanks for everyone's comments.